# python doubly linked list __len__

Tags: python

I cant seem to get my **len** function to work, ive been trying heaps of stuff but im a complete beginner so im pretty sure im missing something completely obvious. This is my code...

```
 def __len__(self):
    if self.head is None:
        return 0
    else:
        return self.size
```

My thinking behind this is simple. If the head of the doubly linked list is None, then it must be empty so return 0, otherwise, just return the size of the list.

However, i get an asssertion error saying...

```
AssertionError: List should contain 1 element, but length is 0
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

EDIT: This is the code thats running my function...

```
testList.add(14)
assert len(testList) == 1, "List should contain 1 element, but length is %r" % len(testList)
```

EDIT2: this is my add function, im pretty sure its right, i spend 2 hours on it...

```
def add(self, value):
    newNode = DoubleListNode(value)
    if self.head is None:
        self.head = newNode
        self.tail  = newNode
        newNode.prev = None
        newNode.next = None
        return newNode
    elif value < self.head.data:
        self.head = newNode
        newNode.next = self.head
        newNode.prev = None
        return newNode
    elif value > self.tail.data:
        self.tail = newNode
        newNode.prev = self.tail
        newNode.next = None
        return newNode
    else:
        node = self.head
        node2 = node
        while node is not None and node.data < value :
            node = node.next
            node2 = node.prev
        newNode.next = node.prev
        newNode.prev = node2.next
        return newNode
```

Comment: Where is the code where you use this list and get that error?

Comment: You'll need to provide the actual code in question

Comment: Don't you need to assert something before you get an `AssertionError`?

Comment: What code is in `add`, and how does `size` get modified?

Comment: Where do you define `testList`? Can you just paste all of the code?

Comment: This is exactly why you need to post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) instead of a random snippet of code that may not contain the bug, can only be understood with knowledge that nobody but you has, and can't be tested in a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `add` function doesn't have anything that will increment `self.size`. So it's whatever you set it to in `__init__`, which is presumably `0`.

So, when the list actually is empty, `__len__` returns `0` because `self.head` is `None`.

And after you add an element, it *still* returns `0` because `self.size` is `0`.

---

Also, your code has at least one other problem in it. Look at this:

```
elif value > self.tail.data:
    self.tail = newNode
    newNode.prev = self.tail
    newNode.next = None
    return newNode
```

Clearly, `newNode.prev` is going to end up pointing at itself, rather than the previous tail.

There are lots of things that can help judge the correctness of code—unit tests, code reviews by someone who didn't work on it, stepping through it with an interactive visualizer, formal proofs, etc.—but the number of hours you worked on it is not one of those things.

Comment: It worked, thank you all for your help. I would have never thought that the problem with my len function was because of my add function!! I must learn to think outside the box!

Comment: +1 -- I wish I could upvote *again* for the statement "There are lots of things that can help judge the correctness of code ... the number of hours you worked on it is not one of those things"